# Why is RadioGroup unchecked

Tags: extjs

I have a radio group

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ColorGrp',{
extend: 'Ext.form.RadioGroup',
xtype: 'colorGrp',
id:'colorGrp',

initComponent: function(){
    colorSchema='1';
    Ext.applyIf(me,{
        value: colorSchema
        items: [
            { boxLabel: Lang.SCHEMA1, name: 'cgrp', inputValue: '0'},
            { boxLabel: Lang.SCHEMA2, name: 'cgrp', inputValue: '1'}
        ]
    });
}
});
```

Why isn't any radio button checked? IMO, the second radio should be checked now!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
colorSchema = { cgrp: '1' }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dy39/